# Adding class to only the first DIV from a set of dynamically created DIV's without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a slideshow in the modal using AngularJS and Bootstrap. So, far I have created DIV's dynamically but my problem is that I have to add the active class to the first DIV only.

How can I do that without using jQuery?

Also, would like to know if this is there any alternative way to achieve the same functionality? Any lead would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="modalApp">
  <head>
    <title>This is a custom modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="modalAppController">

      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#whatsNewModal">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Whats New feature modal -->
<div id="whatsNewModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: #000"><strong><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" style="margin-right: 10px"></i><span>What's New</span></strong></h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body / Modal Content -->

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="whatsNewCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">

            <!-- Carousel Images -->

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carousel-in">

              <div id="carouselContent">

              </div>


            <!-- Carousel Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#whatsNewCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background: transparent">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #dcdde1; top: 40%; left: 10px; font-size: 40px"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#whatsNewCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background: transparent">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #dcdde1; top: 40%; right: 22px; font-size: 40px"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('modalApp', [])
  .controller('modalAppController', modalAppController)
  modalAppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function modalAppController($scope){
    $scope.carouselData = function(src, head, desc){

// Creation of item div

      $scope.carouselCon = document.getElementById("carouselContent");
      $scope.newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
      $scope.newDiv.setAttribute("class", "item active");
      $scope.carouselCon.appendChild($scope.newDiv);


// Creation of Image Element

      $scope.image = document.createElement("img");
      $scope.image.setAttribute("src", src);
      $scope.image.setAttribute("class", "img-fluid d-block");
      $scope.newDiv.appendChild($scope.image);

// Creation of Image Content

      $scope.h3 = document.createElement("H3");
      $scope.h4 = document.createElement("H4");

      $scope.h3Content = document.createTextNode(head);
      $scope.h4Content = document.createTextNode(desc);
      $scope.newDiv.appendChild($scope.h3.appendChild($scope.h3Content));
      $scope.newDiv.appendChild($scope.h4.appendChild($scope.h4Content));

    };

    $scope.carouselData("Screen.png", "Feature 1", "Here goes the description");
    $scope.carouselData("Screen2.png", "Feature 2", "Here goes the description"); // I want to pass more functions like this.
  }
})();
```

Comment: You don't do this stuff in controller.

Comment: So, should I make use of the service? Or is this a good code practice?

Comment: you should make use of angular directives that you can use in templates. ng-repeat, ng-if, ng-class etc.

Comment: Can you throw some more light? Absolute novice here.

Comment: This is worst code practice you can do. And it will guarantee low quality and maintainability problems in future. Read about proper AngularJS workflow, directives, architecture. Start with official tutorial. You want to use directives. Maybe even create new one.

Comment: @s4tr2 well... you should read some tutorials on angular 1.x, because essentially you are not using the features of angularjs that are the main reason to use angularjs. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can select one `div` using `CSS :first-child Selector`.

```
var element = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.classname:first-child' ) );
element.addClass("new_class_name");
```

Comment: Let me know if you are not clear with the code above

Comment: and the fact that the original question (as well as your answer) is a total misuse of angularjs does not bother you?

Comment: Yeah, got it. The problem is that I am an absolute noob in AngularJS but I am trying. Will do that using proper AngularJs

Comment: This question may represent misuse of angular but my answer doesn't.

Comment: @spyshiv yes. it does. modifying DOM elements manually within the controller is a bad practice. You should modify scope variable and let angular directives and digest cycles do their magic.

Comment: @VladimirM Sorry you have misquoted me. I provided a way to achieve result. And I agree with the point `modifying DOM elements manually within the controller is a bad practice.`